# Angular2 Auxiliary Routing

Tags: angular2-routing

I am creating multiple router outlets. The following is the router link to a component I want to load in an outlet called "campaigns".

List

However, it appears to link to /campaigns(campaigns%3Alist) and fails.

How do I get the ":" not to escape?

Comment: How are you generating your aux route?

Comment: The parhs are in routing in the main app.routerlink="campaign(campaigns:list)". It should load the list component in the campaigns router when url is /campaigns.

Comment: where you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to provide `routerLink` as below

```
[routerLink]="['campaigns', {outlets: {campaigns: 'list'}}]"
```

Hope this helps!!